# Batch file -> copying and comparing ASCII files

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv, cmd, ascii

Can anyone help me write this batch file?

1. If there is no csv file inside "copy\" folder, batch file to copy
   "original\file.csv" to "copy\file.txt"
2. Batch file to generate  another csv file with the differences
   between the newest .OK and the "copy/file.txt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point:

`if not exist "copy\file.csv" copy "original\file.csv" "copy\file.csv"`

Second point:

```
@echo off
( for /f "delims=" %%i in (file.txt) do (
    findstr /C:"%%i" file.OK  >nul || echo %%i
  )
)>out.txt
```

Pseudo-Code for better understanding:

```
For each line in file text do:
  Does this line exist in file.OK? If not, write the line...
...to out.txt
```

Comment: 1 - 10MB simple csv file [8 columns, strings]

Comment: @Dalek: What means "differences"? Lines that are only in one of the files? Lines in A, that are not in B? Is one Dataset strictly in one line or may it be, that two or more lines belongs together and may not be separated? Does the order of the lines matter?

Comment: Lines that CAN be found in .txt file and CANNOT be found in the .OK file [both ASCII]. SOrry I forgot to mention that :(